# Performance testing API - WebClient.DownloadData async issue

Tags: c#, .net, performance, task-parallel-library, performance-testing

I am busy doing performance testing on our public API by loading it with parallel, simultaneous calls.  Code below.

```
int batchSize = 10;

ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = batchSize;

Parallel.For(0, batchSize, parallelOptions, j =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Thread began at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        byte[] arr = client.DownloadData("http://myapiurl/webservice.svc");
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    }
});
```

But I am getting weird results:

- From the debug output, I can see that all the threads are starting at the exact same time (as expected).
- I am also recording the time taken to process the API call from within the web service (this is stored in a log table). Each call is taking around about the same time... about 2.5 seconds.
- But now the console output doesn't correlate.  I would expect it to be only slightly longer than what the web service records. Output:

> ```
> 2883 
> 2914 
> 5653 
> 5822 
> 8000 
> 8250 
> 10215 
> 10539 
> 11622 
> 12494
> ```

I can come up with the following possible reasons for this:

- It is as if `WebClient.DownloadData` is queuing up my requests across instances of itself.
- IIS is queuing up my web requests.  This can't be possible as nothing else is hitting the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All HTTP requests are moderated by the ServicePointManager, which manages pools of connections to various hosts. There is a limit for concurrent connections (and therefore HTTP requests) per host. This can be increased with a call to:

```
ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint("http://myapiurl/webservice.svc")
    .ConnectionLimit = 100; //arbitrary value
```

It's also worth remembering that the .Net implementation of HttpWebRequest (which is what `WebClient` uses) can never be truly asynchronous because the DNS lookup occurs synchronously before the request is issued asynchronously. I've always considered this to be an utterly retarded design decision that prevents high performance http requests (esp. in spidering/crawling scenarios).

Comment: Note that the default value for `ConnectionLimit` is just 2, because that's what the HTTP RFC recommends. And you can change the default value by setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` (but you have to do this before making any connections to that service point).